Thunderbolt issue
I have a Mac M1 Ultra. I run 2 BenQ 27" monitors, 2 NVMe external thunderbolt SSD's and a Thunderbolt Audio interface. When I start up 1 ext.drive does not mount. the next time I start the ext. drives mount and the Audio interface does not load. If I unplug 1 of the monitors EVERYTHING works. I need 2 monitors and 2 ssd's and the interface to all work.
I have changed all thunderbolt cables to brand new certified cables. I have done drive repairs. Nothing is wrong with the drives. Is this a weak thunderbolt issue or System?
Mac OS Monterey 12.7.6

Please give your question a more descriptive title. "Thunderbolt issue" is not very specific.
